# MacLaurin series for $9\sec(3x)$

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion, trigonometric-series

A question I've been given asks me to find the first 3 non-zero terms of the MacLaurin series for the function: $y = 9sec(3x)$

Looking at old questions on this forum, I think that this is supposed to be done using the identities: $tan(A) = \frac {sin(A)}{cos(A)}$ and $tan^2(A)+1 = sec^2(A)$ along with the standard series' for $cos(x)$ and $sin(x)$. Wolfram Alpha gave the answer:
$$9sec(3x) = 9+\frac{81x^2}{2}+\frac{1215x^4}{8}+\cdots$$
The method I first attempted in order to answer the question was to simply take the standard series for $cos(x)$ and use this. Like so:
$$sec(A) = \frac 1{cos(A)}$$
therefore
$$9sec(3x) = 9(cos(3x))^{-1}$$
The standard expansion is:
$$cos(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {(-1)^n \frac {x^{2n}}{(2n)!}} = 1-\frac {x^2}{2!}+\frac {x^4}{4!}-\cdots$$
And if I manipulate this to equal $9(cos(3x))^{-1}$, I get:
\begin{align}
9(cos(3x))^{-1} & = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {9\left((-1)^n \frac {(3x)^{2n}}{(2n)!}\right)^{-1}} \\
& = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {9\left[((-1)^n)^{-1} \left(\frac {(3x)^{2n}}{(2n)!}\right)^{-1}\right]} \\
& = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {9\left[(-1)^{-n} \left(\frac {(3x)^{2n}}{(2n)!}\right)^{-1}\right]} \\
& = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {(-1)^{n} \frac {9(2n)!}{(3x)^{2n}}} \\
\end{align}
Which gives the values:
$$9sec(3x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {(-1)^{n} \frac {9(2n)!}{(3x)^{2n}}} = 9-\frac 2{x^2}+\frac 8{3x^4}\cdots$$
Can somebody explain to me where I went wrong?

Comment: $\tan(A)\ne \sec^2(A)$.  And $\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\right)^{-1}\ne \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n^{-1}$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to say: $tan^2(A)+1=sec^2(A)$

Comment: Patrick.  I indicated in the previous comment the point at which the development went wrong. - Mark

Comment: Thank you :) Might you also be able to explain to me how the answer is supposed to be obtained? I'd rather not just right down what WolframAlpha tells me without understanding it first

Comment: You can differentiate repeatedly.  To make the numbers less ugly I would do it with $\sec t$ and do the minor adjustment for $9\sec(3x)$ at the end.  We only need the derivatives of $\sec t$ up to the fourth derivative. Alternately, you can use the series for $\cos t$ and invert. Kind of like long division of polynomials. This will with some computation give you the first few terms. You will not get a "general" formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a tractable way forward to find the coefficients of the series for $\sec(x)$.  It is straightforward to adopt this apply this approach to find the series for $9\sec(3x)$.

Recall that $\sec(x)\,\cos(x)=1$ and that the series for the cosine function is given by

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

Furthermore note that since the secant function is even, its Taylor series will be given by

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

Then, multiplying the series in $(1)$ with the series in $(2)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
1&=\sec(x)\,\cos(x)\\\\
&=\left(\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{a_mx^{2m}}{(2m)!}\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{p=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{m=0}^p \frac{(-1)^{p-m}a_{m}}{(2m)!(2(p-m))!}\right)x^{2p}
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we must have

$$\sum_{m=0}^p \frac{(-1)^{p-m}a_{m}}{(2m)!(2(p-m))!}=\begin{cases}
1&,p=0\\\\
0&,p>0
\end{cases} \tag 1$$

We can use $(1)$ to find the coefficients $a_m$ recursively.  We see that for $p=0$, $(1)$ reveals that $a_0=1$ and for $p>0$ we have the recursive relationship

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{a_p=-(2p)!\sum_{m=0}^{p-1} \frac{(-1)^{p-m}a_{m}}{(2m)!(2(p-m))!}} \tag 2$$

Let's use $(2)$ to find the first few coefficients of the secant function.  For $p=1$, we have

$$a_1=-(2)!\frac{(-1)^{1-0}a_0}{(0)!(2)!}=1$$

For $p=2$, we have

$$a_2=-(4)!\left(\frac{(-1)^{2-0}a_0}{(0)!((4)!)}+\frac{(-1)^{2-1}a_1}{(2)!(2)!}\right)=5$$

For $p=3$, we have

$$a_3=-(6)!\left(\frac{(-1)^{3-0}a_0}{(0)!((6)!)}+\frac{(-1)^{3-1}a_1}{(2)!(4)!}+\frac{(-1)^{3-2}a_2}{(4)!(2)!}\right)=61$$

We can continue recursively to obtain coefficients for higher order terms, but are content here to write the series using the firsts few terms as

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sec(x)=1+\frac x2+\frac{5x^2}{24}+\frac{61x^4}{720}+R_8(x)}$$

where the remainder $R_8(x)$ is

$$R_8(x)=\sum_{p=4}^\infty \left(\sum_{m=0}^p \frac{(-1)^{p-m}a_{m}}{(2m)!(2(p-m))!}\right)x^{2p}=O(x^8)
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, very helpful :)

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  - Mark

Answer (score 0):

$\sec x=(\cos x)^{-1}=[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}]^{-1}\neq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}]^{-1}$
This is the main error you made.
I think an easier way is to obtain the first three terms by long division, that is, take 
$$1/(9\cos3x)=1/(9-9(3x^2)/2!+9(3x^4)/4!-\dots)$$